# How do I see if an array has an integer value when using linq and when inside a where statement?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, integer, contains

`List_Of_Queried_Audio_6 = (from Audio in List_Of_Queried_Audio_5 where(?) select Audio).ToList();`

There is no other code that would be useful for you guys to see. My Audio class is almost completely empty except for a property(with an empty setter and an empty getter) called Speaker.

Let my array be `a`. 
Let my value be `Audio.Speaker`; `Audio` is the same `Audio` you can find in the linq statement. `Speaker` is a property of `Audio`

What should I put to replace the question mark? 
So far, I know that `Array.Exists` and casting the array to an `IList` does not work.

`Array.Exists` does not work because I want to see if `Audio.Speaker` is in my array, and `Audio` is the same `Audio` you can find in the linq statement.

I forgot to mention, I am using C#.

Background

My problem is I need linq to search a column of database and see if a specific row(Audio) has a value that can be found from an array. The array has multiple values ranging from 1-90. The Array can have different values and a different number of values every single time it is used.

Comment: This looks like homework and it looks like you haven't tried anything.

Comment: This isn't homework. I graduated(from college) 2 years ago. I am a freelancer.

Comment: I've already tried Array.Exists and converting an array to an IList.

Comment: Can you post more code? What is the content of the `Audio` class? What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: There is no other code that would be useful. My Audio class is almost completely empty except for a property called Speaker.

Comment: My problem is I need linq to search up to 90 values. The number of values are different every time. My idea is to create an array , in which the possible values will be put into it. Then I can see if a value from a database column matches up with one of the possible values. My List_Of_Queried_Audio_5 already contains the values that can be found in the database column.

Comment: I have made edits to my post in response to howcheng.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you just need to check whether each audio is `contain`ed within your array. You can check that by using the `Contains()` method on arrays:

```
List_Of_Queried_Audio_6 = (from Audio in List_Of_Queried_Audio_5
                           where a.Contains(Audio.Speaker)
                           select Audio).ToList();
```

Comment: No! That is not what I want to do at all.

Comment: Read my question and look at my post carefully.

Comment: @AlexanderKao I did. `I need linq to search a column of database and see if a specific row(Audio) has a value that can be found from an array`... my code does exactly that. For each audio, it checks if it can be found in the array. If that isn't what you need, then please clarify in your question.

Comment: Read my question and my whole post.

Comment: I wanted to delete a post, but stack overflow won't let me. So I just type this instead.

Comment: @AlexanderKao Alright, I fixed my answer by adding `.Speaker` since you say `I want to see if Audio.Speaker is in my array`.

Comment: I've tried that already. It doesn't work because arrays don't have a contains method.

Comment: @AlexanderKao [`Enumerable.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)?... arrays extend `IEnumerable<T>`, so they have a `Contains` method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot of guys. I finally figured out my problem. I can just extract the foreachness from my linq statement so then I can assign my Audio.speakers to something without the word "Audio", which was causing my problems.